# ASP.NET Core 2 localization by url. Generated urls on page have inconsistent language route value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

After login, in `home/index`, urls localization is inconsistent.

This is a solution (ASP.NET Core 2.2) that displays the problem

https://github.com/bonioloa/AspCoreLocalizedSite

Localization code is in the `BaseController`, `Globalfilter`, `Setup`. You can input any value on the field on Login page.

Localization should work by url and if you manually change it (example: localhost/it/Home/Index to localhost/**en**/Home/Index ) and then navigate with enter, I expect that all links generated in page will have a path starting with "en".

If you check source html of this page you can see that Home/Index have the correct path (/en/Home/Index) but Privacy and Logout paths start with the wrong language (/it/), all links are generated with the same asp tag (see _layout.cshtml view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after a good night sleep I changed approach and I finally noticed one thing:

```
SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
```

this directive was breaking localization routing for the first version of my code   implemented using this articles

[Link1](https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet/aspnet-core-simple-localization/)

[Link2](https://irensaltali.com/en/asp-net-core-mvc-localization-by-url-routedatarequestcultureprovider/)

failing to realize that compatibility setting was the root of the problem i made a custom solution that was utterly bugged. Warning: that this setting is shipped with the default ASP.NET Core 2.2 blank solution by visual studio.

I deleted the repository and I recommend to use the template provided in the linked articles.